# Transfer data from one sheet to another by double-click

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My data in sheet1 is in rows and I want to select any row and double-click it and it transfers to sheet2 and appear as a column in sheet2.

Comment: Use `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` method.

Comment: What code should I use?

Answer (score 0):

*This VBA (Macro) will help you to Copy entire Row to another Sheet:*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)


If Target.Column = 1 Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End If

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Copy & Paste this Code as Standard Module.
- Double Click on any Cell in Column A to Copy entire Row.
- This Code will copy Rows one after other without overwriting existing Rows at destination.
- Destination `Sheet 2` is editable.

Comment: How about if I want that data to be transferred to specific cells in the destination sheet?

Comment: @lgTakunda,, check this in code `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`,, currently the code copies data in `Sheet2 A1 downwords`,,, you need to change the column `"A"` to other. Because it's not question of single Row but multiple rows!!

Comment: What I want can be explained with the help of the attached screen-shots

Comment: @lgTakunda but where is the Screen Shot !!

Comment: I couldn't find where to attach screen-shots on the "add comment" box so I have reposted my question with images now.